# Creating pop-up terminal for bash script in python

Tags: python, bash

So the following bit of novice code serves its purpose but the only problem being that the bash script runs within the terminal I'm using the run the rest of the python script, if anyone can help find a way to have the script run in a completely new terminal without closing when done, I would appreciate it.
Thanks.

```
    elif request.lower() == "request arpscan":
        print("Would you like to run ""ArpScan""?")
        arpscananswer = input('>>')
        if arpscananswer.lower() == "yes":
            subprocess.Popen("/BadMuffin/scripts/ArpScanAll")
            print("success, moving back to hub")
```

Comment: You could [run it in another thread.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is happening and what you want to happen. Please give details about the current and desired behavior of each process.